# jQuery selector to find an element based on a data attribute isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to create a jQuery search that will find the element which has just had a data attribute changed. The search isn't working. Here is the Javascript (compiled from CoffeeScript):

```
new_temp_value = "" + (Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000));
console.log("new_temp_value is " + new_temp_value);
$activity_div.data('temp', new_temp_value);
console.log('value of data-temp in $activity_div is now');
console.log($activity_div.data('temp'));
console.log($activity_div.hasClass('activity_div'));
console.log($(".activity_div[data-temp='" + new_temp_value + "']"));
```

Output

```
new_temp_value is 1336020404
value of data-temp in $activity_div is now
1336020404
true
[]
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: IMHO when you manipulate data, the new data value is not written in html..so when you try to find the DOM based on your new data value, it's not found

Comment: What does the declaration of `$activity_div` look like?

Comment: Wait ... you can use **data** as a selector?

Comment: @dbaseman  You can use this statement , `$(".activity_div[data-temp='" + new_temp_value + "']").html();`  and it will still work,if that's what your doubt was. :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you mean to use `.data('temp', '')` or `.attr('data-temp', '')`?  Those are two different things.  Try the latter, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Update using `.attr()`  instead of `.data()`  .  `.data()` doesnt update the DOM as of now.

```
new_temp_value = "" + (Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000));
console.log("new_temp_value is " + new_temp_value);
$activity_div.attr('data-temp', new_temp_value);
console.log('value of data-temp in $activity_div is now');
console.log($activity_div.data('temp'));
console.log($(".activity_div[data-temp='" + new_temp_value + "']"));
```